# Is Eto/Takatsuki Sen the One-Eyed Owl?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

So I was introduced to *Tokyo Ghoul* by watching the anime. I recently started reading the manga and was surprised when I saw this on the character profile on the back-lid of the front cover of *Tokyo Ghoul* volume 14 (the final volume before *:re*):

> [image: eto/takatsuki sen]

I know it is implied that Eto is Takatsuki Sen in the anime and manga, but I don't recall anywhere in the anime where it is revealed that Eto/Takatsuki Sen is the One-Eyed Owl. I also don't think I recall reading in the manga that this was the case (until I saw this image).

Did I miss something? Is Eto/Takatsuki Sen the One-Eyed Owl?

Comment: well that will teach me to *not* skip the postroll credits

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the episode (after the credits) of when Arima beats the One-eyed owl into running away, it is revealed that Eto (Sen Takatsuki) is the One-eyed owl, calling the manager "Father".